# Yammer javascript platform and RequireJS

Tags: jquery, yammer

After latest Yammer update my webapp stopped working because I feel there is a conflict in yam object and my webapp which utilizes requireJS.

Has anyone experienced such issue? have Yammer developers tested it with requireJS?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js shows update date to be : Date: 2014-01-23T21:02Z

How can I get the latest version of JS_SDK? 
Where is the fix that went out JULY 11-th ??

**UPDATE 2**

Here are more specific errors that I'm getting:

GET https://www.yammer.com/tr8n/api/v1/language/translate?batch=true&source=yamjs 401 (Unauthorized) on the page load that has action buttons

and when I click on a button I get another error instead of opening oauth popup.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function yam-requirejs-platform-buttons-ca052fc73277cab0b464f90899829bb5.js:7

It was working without any problem before latest update.

Comment: The date you're seeing there is the date of the jQuery js that is added to the beginning of the Yammer JS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

A fix went out for this on July 11th to resolve the conflict with the yam object that utilize external libraries (specifically requireJS).

If you grab the latest version of the JS SDK (or Embed JS) in your project it should be working now.

Comment: I'm pointing to yammer cdn with [link]https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js . Is this oright?

Comment: Please show me where can I grab the latest version of yammer javascript SDK ? tnx

Comment: The fix you mentioned is not in production yet. open the link on top and you'll see the latest update date.

Comment: I'd love to know too.

Comment: As mentioned above, the date at the top of the JS SDK file is the date of the jQuery version that is included in front of the Yammer JS SDK.